# openGattServer(context, mGattServerCallback) doesn't seem to open a gattserver, why?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

I am trying to create a gattserver in my application, so it can act as a peripheral. First I noticed that the code I wrote for the central (the client) cant connect to the server (the BluetoothGattCallback method onConnectionStateChange delivers the infamous status 113). Then I tried to connect via the Playstore app *nrf connect* which wasn't possible either. The advertising (also done in my code) works though. The client code as well as nrf connect scan for and detect my advertisements.
This is how I wanted to start my server:

```
BluetoothManager mBluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
mGattServer = mBluetoothManager.openGattServer(this, mGattServerCallback);
```

I defined the gattservercallback before, so the line is executed and I get a not NULL BluetoothGattServer instance back, exactly as I wanted, I could even add a service without any problems:

```
btGattServer.addService(createService());
```

(createService returns a Service instance)

I'd really appreciate some help with this!
If anyone needs more details or some more code (e.g. the code that starts the advertising), I'm happy to update my question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself:

To start advertising, you need to call startAdvertising on an Advertiser instance. This call needs three arguments, one of which is an AdvertiseSettings object. When I created this object with the AdvertiseSettings builder I did not include `.setConnectable(true)`.

This was why the advertising itself worked, but applications trying to connect couldn't.
(so `.openGattServer` in fact opened a server it just wasn't connectable)